# js check many variables not equal to empty

Tags: javascript

Maybe this is a duplicate question. But I didn't find any good answer at all.
I want to check multiple variables if not equal to empty('') as below;

```
var list1 = '';
var list2 = 'something';
var list3 = '';
var list4 = 'hello world';
```

**Now I want to check only one variable not equal empty returns true. If more than one variables are not empty returns false**

As I tried

```
if(list1 != '' && list2 != '' && list3 != '' && list4 != ''){
   alert("ALL are filled");
   return false;
}
```

I have no idea how to do it with javascript logical operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array and use `filter` + `length` to get the number of empty items:

```js
var list1 = '';
var list2 = 'something';
var list3 = '';
var list4 = 'hello world';

var list = [list1, list2, list3, list4];

var numberEmptyItens = list.filter((item) => item === '').length;
console.log(numberEmptyItens);
```

Comment: @Andreas True! Edited my answer. Thanks